# Why Does Google's Material Design Not Use Proper Cursor?

Tags: cursor

It seems to me a usability issue to not indicate to the user *clickable* **affordance** on elements such as [tabs](http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-elements/demo.html#paper-tabs) and [sliders](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/paper-elements.html#paper-slider); likewise, it seems odd to me that *disabled* buttons do not have `cursor: not-allowed`.

Is there a reason why Google is avoiding using the proper cursor?  If so, which part of [Material Design](http://www.google.com/design/) does using these cursors violate?  It seems odd to me that they would use `cursor: hover` on [checkboxes](http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-checkbox/demo.html), [radio items](http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-radio-button/demo.html), and buttons, yet that they would not keep a consistent approach for tabs and sliders.

Comment: Material design is made for Android, which is mostly a touch-interface, not a mouse-interface. As far as I could tell, polymer-project is not directly associated with Google, so as far as those css cursor types go, it has to do with Polymer Project.

Comment: @mrcharlie without your comment, I wouldn't have known what this question is about. Asking a web question is totally out of context for android

Comment: Does Material Design even have disabled buttons? Those are usually a bad idea to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Material Design, being thought primary for Android (or better, for every kind of device, included touch screen ones), needs to let users know what the button status is and which kind of action will it do before they click or hover it (touch devices have not hover effect at all).

So every element must have a clear style to being clear at glance, different cursors then become useless.

**nb** this is my personal opionion.